# Closing Popup window using function from the class (kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

I have this class named `AnchorLayoutExample`. (Ignore the errors, it's just for showing all the relevant info.) I want to close the Popup (`popup_window1`) by pressing the exit button (`btn2`) using the function `on_exit_press`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do so?

Thanks for the help.

```
class AnchorLayoutExample(AnchorLayout):

def make_content(self):
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    text1 = TextInput(text='Insert Name', multiline=False, size_hint=(1, .2))
    text2 = TextInput(text='Insert Charge', multiline=False, size_hint=(1, .2))
    btn1 = Button(text='Send')
    btn2 = Button(text='Exit')
    btn2.bind(on_press=self.on_exit_press())
    layout.add_widget(text1)
    layout.add_widget(text2)
    layout.add_widget(btn1)
    layout.add_widget(btn2)
    return layout

def on_button_press1(self):
    show = self.make_content()
    popup_window1 = Popup(title="Insert new expense", content=show, size_hint=(.9, .9))
    popup_window1.open()

def on_exit_press(self):
    self.popup_window1.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change a little in on_button_press1 function. You haven't created any instance variable, but using as instance variable in other function.

Update the function:

```
def on_button_press1(self):
    show = self.make_content()
    self.popup_window1 = Popup(title="Insert new expense", content=show, size_hint=(.9, .9))
    self.popup_window1.open()
```